# Synaptics Touchpad going cray ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchpad, 16.04, synaptics

As i was on ubuntu 14.04 it worked just fine, when i booted ito live mode (16.04) at first it worked with no problem, than it statred flying around. I thought it would go awazy if i install it. After installing it started flying around again. I did some reseach but got nothing that helped me. I also tried other flavours (lxde, xfce, kde). I am new to the linux world so i am not that experienxed. My touchpad is a synaptics one i think it is "i2c".

Comment: It can be a hardware-level problem, please test it once again in 14.04 (no matter booting in live mode or installed, there's almost no difference).

Comment: I updated the bios (because the acer page said it had improvements in the synaptics touchpad), tho the mouse cursor still dances on my desktop! @user300458

Comment: You wrote that on Ubuntu 14.04 it worked just fine. Have you now tested it **again** on 14.04?

Comment: Yes i tried (14.04.4) and it worked correctly.  But when i updated, the problem came back. Any suggestions @user300458 ?

Answer (score 0):

My touchpad don't respond after after I did a recent update for my 14.04. Did some search on internet and found this fix, may be you can try.
Go to TERMINAL and type this command:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo reboot
```

this fix is taken from the forum(much more similar to your case): [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322413)